# What may be an instance of ParameterizedType?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

After reading a documentation of [ParameterizedType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html) interface I thought that an example of ParameterizedType's instance can be any parametrized type such as `col` in my code:

```
  public class a0 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<String> col = new ArrayList<String>();
        col.add("a");
        col.add("b");
        col.add("c");

        assert col instanceof ParameterizedType; // line No. 10
     }
  }
```

But I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
at a0.main(a0.java:10)
```

Thus, what may be an instance of ParameterizedType?

I'd like to know this because I am trying to understand one greater program in which there is such a fragment:

```
public static void printType(Type type) {
...
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
... }
}
```

But I don't know when a condition in `if` statement is true..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ParameterizedType` is a reflective type that *represents* a parameterized type. The parameterized type itself is not an instance of that class.

Similarly, a [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) instance is used to represent a class member field of a certain type. It doesn't mean that such a field would be an instance of `Field`.

An example of a `ParameterizedType` is the following:

```
Type[] genericInterfaces = col.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();
Type type = genericInterfaces[0];

assert type instanceof ParameterizedType;
```